# How to specify the namespace only once when using Castle.Windsor?

Tags: castle-windsor

In the Castle.Windsor demo the configuration file contains

```
<component 
id="form.component"
type="GettingStartedPart1.Form1, GettingStartedPart1" />
```

Why the namespace `GettingStartedPart1` is repeated? Couldn't we write just:

```
<component 
id="form.component"
type="GettingStartedPart1.Form1" />
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not a namespace

when you have

```
"GettingStartedPart1.Form1, GettingStartedPart1"
```

it's:

```
"NamespaceName.TypeName, AssemblyName"
```

So you can't really omit that.

you could have:

```
"System.String, mscorlib"
```

That's not a Windsor's format BTW - it's so called fully qualified type name.